# Problem defining a function out of other working functions

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras

I have a code that creates heatmaps for a given image and then saves it in a given folder. I'm trying to create one function that iterates through a folder with images, creates a heatmap for each of them and saves the image in another folder. So basically, I'm having a problem defining this final loop. All sorts of errors come up, so I would appreciate if you could look at the function itself and maybe suggest where the problems might lie.

This is the code that works if I give it a specific path to an object to generate a heatmap:

```
model_builder = keras.applications.DenseNet121
img_size = (224, 224)
preprocess_input = keras.applications.densenet.preprocess_input
decode_predictions = keras.applications.densenet.decode_predictions

last_conv_layer_name = "conv5_block16_2_conv"

# The local path to our target image
#img_path = "/content/CBIS_DDSM/png_images/calc_case_description_test_set/Calc-Test_P_00038_RIGHT_MLO_1-1.3.6.1.4.1.9590.100.1.2.348569460311013218440657632223354965172-1.3.6.1.4.1.9590.100.1.2.126295284812046209819441424913058621714-000001._BENIGN-roi.png"


display(Image(img_path))
```

```
def get_img_array(img_path, size):
    # `img` is a PIL image of size 299x299
    img = keras.preprocessing.image.load_img(img_path, target_size=size)
    # `array` is a float32 Numpy array of shape (299, 299, 3)
    array = keras.preprocessing.image.img_to_array(img)
    # We add a dimension to transform our array into a "batch"
    # of size (1, 299, 299, 3)
    array = np.expand_dims(array, axis=0)
    return array


def make_gradcam_heatmap(img_array, model, last_conv_layer_name, pred_index=None):
    # First, we create a model that maps the input image to the activations
    # of the last conv layer as well as the output predictions
    grad_model = tf.keras.models.Model(
        [model.inputs], [model.get_layer(last_conv_layer_name).output, model.output]
    )

    # Then, we compute the gradient of the top predicted class for our input image
    # with respect to the activations of the last conv layer
    with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
        last_conv_layer_output, preds = grad_model(img_array)
        if pred_index is None:
            pred_index = tf.argmax(preds[0])
        class_channel = preds[:, pred_index]

    # This is the gradient of the output neuron (top predicted or chosen)
    # with regard to the output feature map of the last conv layer
    grads = tape.gradient(class_channel, last_conv_layer_output)

    # This is a vector where each entry is the mean intensity of the gradient
    # over a specific feature map channel
    pooled_grads = tf.reduce_mean(grads, axis=(0, 1, 2))

    # We multiply each channel in the feature map array
    # by "how important this channel is" with regard to the top predicted class
    # then sum all the channels to obtain the heatmap class activation
    last_conv_layer_output = last_conv_layer_output[0]
    heatmap = last_conv_layer_output @ pooled_grads[..., tf.newaxis]
    heatmap = tf.squeeze(heatmap)

    # For visualization purpose, we will also normalize the heatmap between 0 & 1
    heatmap = tf.maximum(heatmap, 0) / tf.math.reduce_max(heatmap)
    return heatmap.numpy()
```

```
# Prepare image
img_array = preprocess_input(get_img_array(img_path, size=img_size))

# Make model
model = model_builder(weights="imagenet")

# Remove last layer's softmax
model.layers[-1].activation = None

# Print what the top predicted class is
preds = model.predict(img_array)
print("Predicted:", decode_predictions(preds, top=1)[0])

# Generate class activation heatmap
heatmap = make_gradcam_heatmap(img_array, model, last_conv_layer_name)

# Display heatmap
basename = os.path.basename(img_path)
basename, _ = os.path.splitext(basename)

plt.matshow(heatmap)
plt.savefig(os.path.join("/content/CBIS_DDSM/GradCamImages", basename+"_gradcam.png"))
plt.show()
```

** If I run these lines of code I get an image that is then saved in a folder, the problem lies in the function where I try to put it all together and make a loop doing the same for every image in my folder:**

```
def koparka():
    outPath = "/content/CBIS_DDSM/GradCamImages/calc_case_description_test_grad"
    path = "/content/CBIS_DDSM/png_images/calc_case_description_test_set"
    # Make model
    model = model_builder(weights="imagenet")

    # Remove last layer's softmax
    model.layers[-1].activation = None

    # iterate through the names of contents of the folder
    for image_path in os.listdir(path):

        # create the full input path and read the file
        input_path = os.path.join(path, image_path)
        image_to_map = cv2.imread(input_path)


        img_array = preprocess_input(get_img_array(input_path, size=img_size))
       

        # Print what the top predicted class is
        preds = model.predict(img_array)
        print("Predicted:", decode_predictions(preds, top=1)[0])

        # Generate class activation heatmap
        heatmap = make_gradcam_heatmap(img_array, model, last_conv_layer_name)


        # create full output path, 'example.jpg' 
        # becomes 'rotate_example.jpg', save the file to disk
        fullpath = os.path.join(outPath, +image_path)
        misc.imsave(fullpath, heatmap)

if __name__ == '__koparka__':
    koparka()
```

If I try to run `koparka()` I get an error, this time the following (I was making multiple changes trying to solve the problem and each time there was a different one):

```
WARNING:tensorflow:9 out of the last 9 calls to <function Model.make_predict_function.<locals>.predict_function at 0x7f1232648170> triggered tf.function retracing. Tracing is expensive and the excessive number of tracings could be due to (1) creating @tf.function repeatedly in a loop, (2) passing tensors with different shapes, (3) passing Python objects instead of tensors. For (1), please define your @tf.function outside of the loop. For (2), @tf.function has experimental_relax_shapes=True option that relaxes argument shapes that can avoid unnecessary retracing. For (3), please refer to https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/function#controlling_retracing and https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/function for  more details.
Predicted: [('n06359193', 'web_site', 3.4884915)]
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-47-b16d1bac302d> in <module>()
----> 1 koparka()

<ipython-input-46-9b9d3280b9e1> in koparka()
     30         # create full output path, 'example.jpg'
     31         # becomes 'rotate_example.jpg', save the file to disk
---> 32         fullpath = os.path.join(outPath, +image_path)
     33         misc.imsave(fullpath, heatmap)
     34 

TypeError: bad operand type for unary +: 'str'
```

Comment: What's your intent with `+image_path`? Did you remove a string from before that and forget to remove the `+`?

Comment: This is exactly what happened, there was a string there I removed, as I wanted the files to keep original name. I got it working after correcting it. Thanks!